# Stripe callback in AngularJS only handled when I click Save button twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, stripe-payments

In my AngularJS controller I have this:

```
  ....

  stripeResponseHandler = function (status, response) {
    if(response.error) {
      Toaster.pop('rejected', 'cross', 'We could not validate your card.');
    }
  }

  $scope.handleNewCard = function () {
    Stripe.card.createToken({
      number: $scope.number,
      cvc: $scope.cvc,
      exp_month: $scope.exp_month,
      exp_year: $scope.exp_year,
      name: $scope.name,
      address_line1: $scope.address_line1,
      address_line2: $scope.address_line2,
      address_zip: $scope.address_postcode,
      address_city: $scope.address_city,
      address_country: $scope.address_country
    }, stripeResponseHandler);
  };

  ...
```

In my view I have this:

```
.col-xs-6
   a.btn.large.blue.pull-left(ng-click='handleNewCard()')
    | Save
```

The problem is that the callback function is only handled when I click the Save button twice.
The weird thing is also that if I just do a console.log in the callback it shows it every time but the Toaster.pop is only done when I click the save button twice.

Comment: Are you putting the `console.log` inside or outside of the `if(response.error)` statement?

Comment: console.log is outside the if(response.error) to check if the callback is happening everytime I click. It is happening everytime but the Toaster.pop is not happening, even if I put that outside the if check as well. For Toaster.pop to trigger I have to click the save button twice.

Comment: Dump `response` to the console - is `response.error` set on the iterations that `Toaster.pop` doesn't pop? My guess is not.